# I can't connect to paypal api in prestashop

Tags: paypal, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When i click on paypal button to access to paypal interface from prestashop 1.6  i get this error :

PayPal response:
SILOVER name=LIVE9.APIT.1&silo_version=880&app=appdispatcher_apit&TIME=1296937557; domain
TIMESTAMP -> 2015-07-24T14:35:57Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute this commands at your server:

```
apt-get install php5-curl
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Source: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/419670-paypal-module-suddenly-stopped-working/

Comment: Mark answer as solution is appreciated :)